# how to keep checkbox checked after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

So I am trying to keep the checkbox checked after the page gets refresh I am using the following script but when page refreshes it makes all other check boxes checked.
**ALSO MAKE A NOTE INPUT ARE DYNAMICALLY GENERATED CANT BE HARD CODED SO I CANT PUT DIFFERENT ID's TO DIFFERENT INPUT**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    jQuery('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

jQuery('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = jQuery(this).is(':checked');
    console.log(jQuery(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

consider the following checkboxes to be in code

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: You need some way to distinguish the checkboxes, so you can save each of them separately in local storage and then check them properly when refreshing.

Comment: That *bold* note in your question is the problem, fix it and you will get the solution. Dynamic generation does not restrict you from having different IDs assigned to checkboxes.

Comment: @niksofteng that is not the issue it has to be dynamically generated via PHP function in magento

Comment: @Barmar and how to do that?

Comment: Is there at least a parent element to those checkboxes?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes <div> is there and I have class name of all input

Answer (score 6):

You can save all the checkboxes as a JSON array, and then restore them by looping through the array.

```
jQuery(function(){
    if (localStorage.input) {
        var checks = JSON.parse(localStorage.input);
        jQuery(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(i) {
            return checks[i];
        });
    }
});

jQuery(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = JSON.stringify(jQuery(':checkbox').map(function() {
        return this.checked;
    }).get());
});
```